# UICollectionView cell needs to be tapped twice for segue to happen

Tags: uicollectionview

I know this will be something simple; however, I have created a UICollectionView that displays just some colours for now. When a cell is tapped I want it to perform a segue with the cell number that was tapped.

At the moment, if I tap a cell nothing happens. If I touch the same cell again nothing happens, but if I touch any other cell the segue occurs successfully and the cell clicked gets passed on, albeit with the first cells touched number.

It is in a navigation stack. Here is my code:

```
//Everything Collection View


//header text
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SectionHeaderPractice
    header.headerLabel.text = "SELECT A TOPIC..."
    return header
}

//number of cells
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

//height and width of cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellWidth = (view.frame.width/2)-20
    let cellHeight = view.frame.height/4
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
}

//cell content

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let content = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    //set text
    let desc = content.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    desc.text = shieldTextArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    //set color scale
    let score = scoreArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    let redC = 2*score
    let greenC = 2*(1-score)
    content.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: CGFloat(redC), green: CGFloat(greenC), blue: 0.45, alpha: 1)

    return content
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //sets variable to clicked cell
    //cellClicked = indexPath.row

    //changes background colour on clicking
    //let content1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    //content1.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    //Performs segue
    //print(cellClicked)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "practiceSegue", sender: self)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)
}

//End Everything Collection View
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with this line `didDeselectItemAt`, make sure you use `didSelectItemAt`.

`didDeselectItemAt` is the reason why you have to tap twice for segue, you select the cell then deselect the cell, once the cell is deselected, your code perform segue.

Comment: Thank you so much... can't believe I missed that!